# PHP str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting this error while running my app:

> PHP str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type
> array|string is deprecated

I am Using CodeIgniter Version : V4.1.8 PHP Version : 8.1.2, full error output below:

```
{"data":[
    ["omron","<span class=\"label label-success\">Active<\/span>",
    "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onclick=\"editBrand(4)\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#editBrandModal\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\"><\/i><\/button> <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onclick=\"removeBrand(4)\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#removeBrandModal\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"><\/i><\/button>\n\t\t\t\t"]
    ]
}
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: 8192</p>
<p>Message:  str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated</p>
<p>Filename: core/Output.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 457</p>


    <p>Backtrace:</p>
```

UPDATE: Code

```
if ($this->parse_exec_vars === TRUE) 
{ 
    $memory = round(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024, 2).'MB'; 
    // below is line 457
    $output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output); 
}
```

Comment: I get the feeling that it would be useful to see the actual code that this error message is complaining about..... Dont you?

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Also as `core/Output.php` sounds like codeigniter code, look back up the stack trace to see what piece of your code called this code code and show us that. That is probably where the issue occurs

Comment: I cant able to copy /paste my entire code

Comment: 454 if ($this->parse_exec_vars === TRUE)
455  {
456  $memory = round(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024, 2).'MB';
457  $output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output);
458  }

Comment: Please always put code into the question. There s an [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70954797/edit) link under the question. Use this as often as you like to improve/add to your question any details requested of you

Comment: I have updated this, still that showing the same ?

Comment: OK, so now show us whats in `$output` please. A `var_dump($output);` And all the other relevant variables

Comment: These are the scenerios happened to me

Comment: I am Using CodeIgniter Version : V4.1.8
PHP Version : 8.1.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message can show up if you have not loaded any views.  Codeigniter's internal output buffer is never initialized thus being `null`.  The output buffer is the third parameter to `str_replace()`.  There might be other ways to trigger this error message.

You probably want to load a valid view, at some point.

PHP 7 and lower just would ignore the missing parameter, while PHP 8+ displays the warning.  It may also vary with your environment / debug settings.

Answer (score 30):

***Using a ternary operator will fix this error.***

**Before Codeigniter existing code:**

```
$output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output);
```

Hopefully, it's will work fine as we will escape str_replace for a null value.

**After Using Ternary Operator:**

```
$output = $output ? str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output): "";
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Error in codeigniter's `Output.php` file `(system/core/Output.php)` You need to replace `$output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output);` This with `$output = $output ? str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output): ""; ` . It is at line no. 457 in system/core/Output.php

Comment: for CI 3.x projects: this is fixed with the [3.1.13 release](https://api.github.com/repos/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/zipball/refs/tags/3.1.13): either upgrade the whole installation or just replace the `system/core/Output.php` file, depending on your needs....

Comment: Altering System / Framework code should really be an ultra-last resort, especially since your patch will likely be overwritten with any framework update.

Comment: Rather than the embedding the ternary operator in the call, I would do this above that line. I think it's clearer:

      `$output = $output === null ? '' :  $output;`

Answer (score 3):

i think i found the issue , it is not a direct problem from **str_replace()** function , codeigniter written this perfectly , but you are using **strip_quotes()** function somewhere , and you are passing directly something to it like :

```
$d= strip_quotes($this->input->post('thusnder'));
```

if it is , then you must update your code by adding this :

```
$d= strip_quotes($this->input->post('thusnder') ?? '');
```

this will prevent data to be null and then it will not be passed to the **strip_quotes()** function which uses **str_replace()**

hope it will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

I  also faced same issue just used these lines in your Controller constructor method

```
 public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    error_reporting(0);
    $this->load->library("session");
    $this->load->helper('url');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check $output in the existing if statement. That will skip the entire block of code that isn't needed when $output is NULL or empty.

```
if ($this->parse_exec_vars === TRUE && !empty($output)) 
{ 
    $memory = round(memory_get_usage() / 1024 / 1024, 2).'MB'; 
    // below is line 457
    $output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), $output); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user this code to get rid of it:

```
$output = str_replace(array('{elapsed_time}', '{memory_usage}'), array($elapsed, $memory), (string) $output );
```

Answer (score 0):

As for as this error is `Deprecated`, so can't effect on your website behavior. You can disable PHP Deprecated warnings in your host manager (cpanel):

1. Log into cPanel.
2. Go to Home » Software » MultiPHP INI Editor.
3. Click the "Editor Mode" tab.
4. Choose intended domain from the dropdown.
5. Find and edit/replace (or add if there is not) the "error_reporting" section using the following line :

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

6. save

Hope it works!

Answer (score -2):

I have had such an error

This is the only way to get rid of the error. That you PHP 7 & 8 install you'r System

php install in c/:xampp &  c/:xampp2  installed.
beacuse difrant drive in error occuerd

And

Benefit in other programs

[Multiple xampp installations windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejJXgseW4T0&t=1s)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not get meaning of "php install in c/:xampp & c/:xampp2 installed" please write in clear way so that other can understand.

Answer (score -6):

I Have downgraded my CI version to 3 and PHP verison to 7.3

Its working now

Comment: Downgrading is a workaround, at best.  Better to find the actual problem and fix it.

Comment: Downgrading the PHP version should not be the solution not sure why this was marked as the fix?